# Dockerfile (FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:17-jre) chromedriver java

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux

I have Dockerfile code, that works correct 3 months ago and now don't work :/
Do you know what is the problem ?

my code:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:17-jre

RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -D -S spring -G spring

RUN mkdir -p data/log/zocdocbot
RUN find data/log/zocdocbot/ -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} \;
RUN find data/log/zocdocbot/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

RUN mkdir -p data/screenshot
RUN find data/screenshot/ -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} \;
RUN find data/screenshot/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

RUN mkdir -p config/driver/chromedriver-linux
RUN find config/ -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} \;
RUN find config/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
RUN find config/driver/chromedriver-linux/ -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} \;
RUN find config/driver/chromedriver-linux/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

ADD config/ /config/
RUN chmod 0777 /config/zocdocbot.properties
RUN chmod 0777 /config/driver/chromedriver-linux/chromedriver

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash \
    alsa-lib \
    at-spi2-atk \
    atk \
    cairo \
    cups-libs \
    dbus-libs \
    eudev-libs \
    expat \
    flac \
    gdk-pixbuf \
    glib \
    libgcc \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    libpng \
    libwebp \
    libx11 \
    libxcomposite \
    libxdamage \
    libxext \
    libxfixes \
    tzdata \
    libexif \
    udev \
    xvfb \
    zlib-dev \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /tmp/*

RUN chown -R spring:spring /data
USER spring:spring

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} bot-app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx248M","-Xss512K","-XX:+UseContainerSupport","-Xlog:gc","-jar","/bot-app.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 4444
EXPOSE 9222
EXPOSE 9223

ENV PATH="/usr/bin/chromedriver:${PATH}"

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx250M -Xss256K -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xlog:gc -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
ENV JVM_OPTS="-Xmx246M -Xss256K -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xlog:gc -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

and after run i have error:

```
Jul 28 07:53:34 PM  #23 0.396 OK: 17824 distinct packages available
Jul 28 07:53:34 PM  #23 0.433 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
Jul 28 07:53:34 PM  #23 0.564 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
Jul 28 07:53:35 PM  #23 0.783 ERROR: unable to select packages:
Jul 28 07:53:35 PM  #23 0.814   at-spi2-atk (no such package):
Jul 28 07:53:35 PM  #23 0.814     required by: world[at-spi2-atk]
Jul 28 07:53:35 PM  #23 0.814   atk (no such package):
Jul 28 07:53:35 PM  #23 0.814     required by: world[atk]
Jul 28 07:53:35 PM  #23 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apk update && apk add --no-cache bash     alsa-lib     at-spi2-atk     atk     cairo     cups-libs     dbus-libs     eudev-libs     expat     flac     gdk-pixbuf     glib     libgcc     libjpeg-turbo     libpng     libwebp     libx11     libxcomposite     libxdamage     libxext     libxfixes     tzdata     libexif     udev     xvfb     zlib-dev     chromium     chromium-chromedriver     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*     /usr/share/man     /tmp/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

i look for in google but i cant find any solution :/ Is this problem with some arguments or with the image ?
can i replace this image with another one that will be similar to chromedriver and take up little space?

regards

Comment: i was able to solve the problem. packages: at-spi2-atk and atk, should be replaced with package: at-spi2-core ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve the problem.
packages: at-spi2-atk and atk, should be replaced with package: at-spi2-core.
now it is working